# Using PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment without creating a hierarchy

Tags: android

It seems that from the android developer docs, they provided an example on how to create preferences with heiarchy and headers.

Is there a way to create the preference without headers? I saw there's the EXTRA_NO_HEADER but I'm not too sure how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just create your PreferenceActivity, or ~Fragment, depending on the API level/support library presence. The beginning of the tutorial starts just with your question: [Settings @ Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity)